# Raspberry Pi doesn't run script on autostart

Tags: sh, raspberry-pi3, autostart

I've tried to start a shell script on my Raspberry Pi 3.

I wrote the path in rc.local. This worked for all other scrpits but not for the one below. I think the script starts (if I add a "sleep" the terminal opens after start) but doesn't work at this time. When I start the script by hand it works fine.
Has somebody a clue?

```
#!/bin/bash
status=$( cat status.txt )

if [ $status == 0 ]
then
    ./s0.sh
fi

if [ $status == 1 ]
then
    ./s1.sh
fi

if [ $status == 2 ]
then
    ./s2.sh
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is that you have to use absolute pathes to the scripts. Using /home/pi/Dektop/s0.sh and so on will work